# What is the fastest drawing method on iOS?

Tags: ios, performance, opengl-es

I'm developing a 2D game on iOS, but I'm finding it difficult getting drawing to run fast (60 FPS on Retina display).

I've first used UIKit for drawing, which is of course not suitable for a game. I coulnd't draw a couple of sprites without slowdown.

Then I moved on to OpenGL, because I read it's the closest I can get to the GPU (which I think it means it's the fastest possible). I was using glDrawArrays(). When I ran it on the Simulator, FPS dropped when I was reaching over 200 triangles. People said it was because the Simulator or the computer are not optimized to run iOS OpenGL. Then I tested it on a real device, and to my surprise, the performance difference was really small. It still couldn't run that few triangles smoothly - and I know other games on iOS use a lot more polygons, shaders, 3D graphics, etc.

When I ran it through Instruments to check OpenGL performance, it told me I could speed it up by using VBOs. So I rewrote my code to use VBO instead, updating all vertices each frame. Performance increased very little, and I still can't surpass 200 triangles at consistent 60 FPS. And that is 2D drawing alone without context changes/transformations. I also didn't write the game yet - there are no objects making no CPU-intensive tasks.

Everyone I ask says OpenGL is top performance. What could I possibly be doing wrong? I am assuming OpenGL can handle LOTS of polygons that are updated each frame - is that right? Which method other games use that I see they run fine, like Infinity Blade which is 3D, or even Angry Birds which has lots of ever-updating sprites? What is recommended when making a game?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is definitely going to be your fastest option. Even on the oldest iOS devices you can run about 20,000 polygons at 30+ fps.

Sounds like you must be doing something wrong or extra. It is impossible to try to guess what that might be without seeing your source code.

Generally speaking though, you want to make sure you create your VBO and all your loading outside of your drawing pipeline.

Comment: Loading is being done only at the beginning of the game, and I use only very few state change calls. But I don't understand when you say Drawing Pipeline... I mean, I must update my vertices every frame, and as drawing also occurs every frame, I thought those two happened at the "same" time. How can I separate them? I'm trying to time profile my code, but I don't fully understand what's going on on Instruments...

Comment: Drawing Pipeline is your drawing loop. I can't help you without seeing what you are doing. I still suspect that you must be doing something inside your drawing loop that you shouldn't be doing.